# Why does Essential matrix has 2 euqal singular values and 1 zero singular values?

Tags: computer-vision

[image]

[image]
[image]

I was watching the lecture about an essential matrix. and the professor was teaching eight-point linear algorithm. I understood that we need 8 points to estimate the essential matrix. But in this slide, he said that the estimated matrix doesn't correspond to an essential matrix and we should project that matrix it to the essential space. And he didn't prove this theorem, and just skipped it.

So I have some questions

1. Why does an essential matrix has two equal singular values, and a zero singular value?
2. Why should we average the two largest singular values that is obtained from eight-point algorithm in order to make an essential matrix?

Comment: If the lecture was not a video you should really ask him in person (and then do not hesitate to post an answer below). If it was a video please share URL and timestamp.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9fvopDHdrFg&list=PLNbgPw_3QpygF-BLrW9V0HEAr79tlS63s&index=8
This is url and the time is after 1:09:54

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asking your first question.

The singular values of the esential matrix E are the square-roots of the eigenvalues of EE^t. We know that E = TR where R is a rotation matrix and T=[0,-z,y;z,0,-x;-y,x,0] then we have EE^t=TRR^tT^t=TT^t.

Also T is a singular skew-symmetric matrix then we can decompose it as T=P^t[0,k,0;0,-k,0;0,0,0]P where P is an orthogonal matrix.

Replacing this in the previous formula we have EE^t=P^t[-k^2,0,0;0,-k^2,0;0,0,0]P=P^tUP then E is a normal matrix and the eigenvalues are the diagonal elements of U.

I have used Matlab notation to denote matrices and A^t denotes the transpose of the matrix A.